# Stop Textbox firing OnClientClick event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The combination of pressing enter on a textbox with a page that has an image button with both a client and server click event is causing the client side event to fire when I press enter in the textbox.

I want to prevent this, am happy to use Jquery or whatever is best. From the Jquery side am struggling to capture the enter key

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:ImageButton ID="CancelImageButton" ImageUrl="Cancel.gif"   
runat="server"  OnClientClick="alert(); return false;" 
onclick="Cancel_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested at my end and found you did not pass the alert message. That's why it is not working.

```
 OnClientClick="javascript:alert('Hello'); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using server-side and client-side TextBox's events, why don't you try HtmlInputText?

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext(v=VS.100).aspx

So you can use jQuery to bind an event handler to this control.

Perhaps you can take a look to this jQuery event object method:

- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/